# FFMPEG video joiner

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am working on merging videos, but is not merging my videos. Here is the code

`exec(cat file1.flv file2.flv > trailer/output.flv);

exec("ffmpeg -i trailer/output.flv -sameq trailer/output.flv);`

But if the size of file1 is 1MB and file2 is 2MB and output is coming as 3MB. But it is playing only the file1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.flv -i input2.flv {other parameters if needed} ouput.flv
```

will join two files for you.

Comment: it will only output the first flv video as a output, instead of joining with other.

Answer (score 0):

You can not simply merge FLV files using cat, because at the beginning of output file there will be header from first file.

This post may be helpful:

http://albanianwizard.org/splitting-and-joining-flv-files-under-linux-with-ffmpeg-and-avidemux.albanianwizard

I know it's maybe possible with **mencoder** like this:

```
mencoder -ovc lavc file1.flv file2.flv -o complete.avi
```